# Text moving out of position sometimes in UWP app

Tags: xaml, layout, uwp, windows-phone-emulator

So I have this code for my MainPage for example:

```
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" >
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="640" Margin="0,-20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/start-01.jpg"/>
        </Canvas.Background>
        <Image x:Name="play" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="78,281,0,325" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="play_Tapped"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="playTB" Height="34" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="RACE" FontSize="30" CharacterSpacing="364" Tapped="play_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="125" Canvas.Top="279" />
        <Image x:Name="highscoresBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="78,335,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="highscoresBT_Tapped"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="highscoreTB" Height="34" Margin="88,335,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="HIGHSCORES" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="100" Tapped="highscoresBT_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode"/>
        <Image x:Name="storeBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="34" Margin="78,398,0,0" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="storeBT_Tapped"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="storeTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="111,392,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="STORE" Width="151" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="364" Tapped="storeBT_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="helpBut" Height="96" Margin="115,511,122,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Assets/helpBut-01.png" Tapped="helpBut_Tapped" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
        <Image x:Name="coinsBG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="294,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Source="Assets/comp bar-01.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image x:Name="coinsIC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="14" Source="Assets/coins-01.png" Margin="328,13,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="coinsOwnedTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="302,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="21" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257"/>
        <Image x:Name="scoreBG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Source="Assets/comp bar-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="12,12,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="scoreNameTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Score: " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257" Canvas.Left="13" Canvas.Top="11"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="scoreTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="15000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Foreground="#FF535257" Canvas.Left="61" Canvas.Top="11" Margin="0,1,0,0"/>
        <Image x:Name="feedbackBT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="78,461,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Source="Assets/start bottuns-01.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="feedback_Tapped"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="feedbackTB" Height="34" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SUPPORT" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="feedback_Tapped" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" TextAlignment="Center" CharacterSpacing="200" Canvas.Left="91" Canvas.Top="458"/>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

the problem is the TextBlocks on top of the images sometimes for some reason moves up a bit on  the Windows Phone Emulator (all sizes), it doesn't happen when launching on Local Machine (BTW I use VS 2015).
look at the too examples:

[image: 1)The Original text position]

this is how it should be and this is how it turns out sometimes:
[image: 2)the moved text]

Notice TextBlocks Like RACE moved up a bit, what is confusing is that this doesn't happen always I run the app 5 times in a row 2 will be good and 3 with this text shift.

Anyone has any Idea of a possible cause for this, or maybe its just the emulator problem and on actual phones it should be fine ? 
Thanks

Comment: I don't have any of your image resources, just run your code, it shows like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBCoK.png) running on local machine. This is mainly because your ViewBox's `Stretch` property is `Uniform` and your canvas margin is like this: `Margin="0,-20,0,0"`. Anyway, I don't think an absolutely layout would adapt to different device, you may consider to change your layout. And in addition, you can simply use `Button` control instead of combining `Image` and `TextBlock`. If you need a sample for this, please leave a comment and I will post an answer.

Comment: Actualy  the viewbox stretch doesn't have anything to do with it I added it recently and this problem was already there same goes for the -20 in the margin of the canvas ,  and actually it adapts pretty well using the view box ,I certainly can use buttons here but on things like the score and coins it has to be text on top of an image that is why I'm wondering what the problem may be, and as I said running it several times gives different result each time its a bit weird but there should be a hidden reason

Comment: To clarify I added the whole viewbox recently not jut the strech bit. And the problem was already there.

Comment: Just for example of `Button` which its text on top of an image: `<Button Width="200">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/border.jpg" />
    </Button.Background>
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Scroe: " />
            <TextBlock Text="0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>`

Comment: yep I understand this and I did fix my buttons like this I know it was silly to build the button this way from the start, but as I pointed out my problem doesn't end in  button there are couple of places like the coins tab on the top right of the screen that just have to be image and text not a button.

Comment: and beside all that, even if I can workaround all this I'm still curious to find as to why such phenomena happens in the first place ,why just on the phone emulator and why sometimes it right and sometimes not when nothing changed in the code,